# Having a hard time using getchar and storing characters

Tags: c, input, getchar

I am new to programming in C and still trying to learn all of the useful functions it provides in its libraries. In particular I'm trying to wrap my head around how to use getchar() for more than one character in a certain situation. I want to be able to have input from the console be something like:

11 2 34 100

I want to be able to distinguish between these entries(delimiter space I guess?), and add these numbers up. This is an assignment, so I was wondering if someone could give me a hint or point me in the right direction on how to go further with this. I would certainly appreciate it. This is what I have at the moment. Also, we're not supposed to make use of arrays here. This really threw me because I don't see any other way. Again any help or pointers in the right direction would go a long way!

```
   int main()
{


  int count = 0;
  char input;
  int wordCount = 0;
  int numEntered  = 0;


  input = getchar();

  while(input != '\n')
    {
      if(input != ' ')
    {

          count++;

    }

      input = getchar();

    }

  printf("Number of characters included in numbers %d\n", count);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should read your characters into an `int`, not a `char`. The magic value `EOF` that indicates the end of a file does not have a unique character representation.

Comment: If I remember correctly isn't the end of a file indicated by a -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store two integers, one that is the running total, and one that is the current number.

If you encounter a digit that is not a space, multiply the current number by 10 and then add that digit to the current number.

If you encounter a space, add the current number to the running total, then reset the current number to 0.

Comment: I was originally thinking about some idea like that, sort of quasi integer concatenation. I will give this a try and report back. Thank you.